# ListWheelScrollView do not recognize taps

Tags: flutter

The children of a ListWheelScrollView do not recognize taps. How can I make the children of a ListWheelScrollView recognize taps? I think there is some kind of scrollable widget infront of the children which is preventing the children from being clicked. If I put this code inside of a listview, everything works fine, but not for a listWheelScrollView

```
class _ScrollWheelPageState extends State<ScrollWheelPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ListWheelScrollView(
            itemExtent: 100,
            o
            onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
              print(index);
            },
            useMagnifier: false,
            children: List.generate(
              10,
              (index) => FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print(index);
                },
                child: Image.asset("images/provider4.png"),
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: use `nestedScrollview` instesd of that ,,

Comment: It looks like that this is a issue in ListWheelScrollView https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38803.

Comment: any example  @AjayMistry